# Expanding an array column in a Spark dataframe to individual columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to expand an array column such that each element in the array becomes a column in the dataframe?

The dataframe contains an array column and the size of the array is not fixed. Meaning, the array column in the first row can have n elements and the array column in the second row can have m elements.

I have tried the explode() function but that's splits the array into rows and not columns.

```
Input dataframe
+---+------------------------------------------+
|id |arr                                       |
+---+------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{cid = a, pid = 12}, {cid = b, pid = 13}]|
|2  |[{cid = c, pid = 12}]                     |
+---+------------------------------------------+

Expected dataframe
+---+--------------------------------------------------+
|id |arr_12_cid | arr_12_pid | arr_13_cid | arr_13_pid |
+---+--------------------------------------------------+
|1  |a          | 12         | b          | 13         |
|2  |c          | 12         | null       | null       |
+---+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It is probably not possible in parallel mode. Because each row can have some column which does not exist for other rows, and you cannot change the schema in a parallel case. Hence, the reasonable way is iterating over the whole of the rows from start to end.

Comment: Can be done but very convoluted - for the new year

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of array in a separate column, find the max and then iterate

```
val dataDF = Seq((1, Array("a", "b", "c", "d")), (2, Array("a", "b"))).toDF("id", "data")
val z = dataDF.withColumn("data_length", functions.size($"data")).selectExpr("max(data_length)").head().getInt(0)
dataDF.select((0 until z).map(r => dataDF.col("data").getItem(r)): _*).show()
```